# Subversion: svn status displays tons of undesired .metadata files

Tags: svn, version-control, configuration

I'm trying to set up Subversion on Ubuntu Linux.  It seems to be working, except that when I made one change and tried `svn status`, I found about 100 files had been changed, in the `.metadata` directory.

My ~/.subversion/config file currently contains the following line:

```
global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo *.rej *~ .*.swp .DS_Store
```

What do I need to add to ignore the .metadata files?

The directory under consideration is used by Eclipse for Python development using PyDev, if that matters.

Answer (score 47):

You can ignore unversioned files with status by running:

```
svn status --quiet
```

Comment: This also ignores unchanged files.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply instruct your svn to ignore that directory entirely:

```
 svn propset svn:ignore path/to/.metadata
```

More details in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn/116097#116097).

Note: in this case, I would recommend having your Eclipse project defined (.project, .classpath) outside the `.metadata` Eclipse directory.
That way, you can:

- safely ignore that `.metadata` tree
- be able to version (if you want) the definition of your Eclipse project in order to re-import it easily in a new workspace if you need it.

See the SO question "[Do you keep your project files under version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116121/do-you-keep-your-project-files-under-version-control/119377#119377)"

Comment: When I try the `propset` command I get `property 'svn:ignore' set on '/home/eric/Python/.metadata'` but the same result for `svn status`.
I don't think my Eclipse project is in my `.metadata` tree at all.