# Eclipse: which files to store in version control for GWT project

Tags: eclipse, version-control, gwt, mercurial

I'm working on a GWT project in Eclipse with Mercurial for revision control.

Which files should I store under version control? Or, perhaps more succinctly, which files should I *not* store since they are either part of GWT or are artifacts of the build process?

I'm using Eclipse Helios and GWT 2.0.4. This question would apply to any version control system: Mercurial, Subversion (SVN), CVS, etc.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410081/what-directories-files-should-be-ignored-when-commiting-eclipse-workspaces-to-ve

Answer (score 2):

If your project is located *outside* your workspace, I would store everything but:

- the `bin` or `cls` (that is the directory where `.class` files are generated).
- any [directory/file with *generated* content](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/create.html)

Make sure you take advantage of [relative paths in your `.project`/`.classpath`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818239/classpath-and-project-check-into-version-control-or-not/2819639#2819639) (since Eclipse 3.5.2)