# Where does Eclipse/Java store project compliance?

Tags: java, eclipse, git

every time me or one of our team members pull one of our project Eclipse asks to set project compliance to 1.8. 
The problem is most likely a file pushed to git that would rather not be tracked in version control at all. 
Now how and where is project compliance stored, so that I can fix the project.

Thanks in advance

Paul

Comment: You should check that you are using some **syntax** or **feature** that only exist in java 1.8 or above.

Comment: See also [Eclipse: which files to store in version control for GWT project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182809/eclipse-which-files-to-store-in-version-control-for-gwt-project).

Answer (score 1):

This is stored in a `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` file which is a Java Properties file. The compliance setting is this entry:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=13
```

If you have project specific settings enabled the file is in the `.settings` directory in the project root.

For the global Preference compliance setting the file is in the workspace `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` directory.