# In Indigo with CCRC 7.1, The clearcase menu buttons on the Java EE perspective are disabled. How can I enable them?

Tags: eclipse, clearcase-remote-client

In my eclipse Indigo installation, I have the clearcase remote client (CCRC) perspective working - it's connecting the server just fine and the functionality is there.  However, in the Java EE perspective most of the buttons are disabled.

When I edited a file in the Java EE perspective, it used to ask (with a previous version of CCRC and eclipse ganymede) if I wanted to check it out.  However, now it merely asks if I want to make the file writable (default eclipse behaviour).

Basically most of the CCRC functionality in the Java EE perspective is disabled.  I can see the buttons in the toolbar, but they are disabled (greyed out).  Clearcase is also not showing up in the right-click context menu under Team.

Thoughts?

Comment: I think it's a design. You don't import projects controlled by Clearcase into your workspace.

Comment: Are you sure that file is within a (snapshot or dynamic) view? Are you sure the `.project` and `.classpath` of that JEE project are within the same ClearCase view?

Comment: the .project and .classpath are not part of the ClearCase view.  Is this necessary?  We can make that happen, but currently we're adding the files via New->Source Folder.  However, the functionality I'm looking for used to exist in previous versions of CCRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All recent CCRC (7.1.x) settings I managed are build on the same premiss:
That the `.project` and `.classpath` are part of the snapshot 'web' view which is a CCRC view.
That is what indicates eclipse that this eclipse project is managed under source control.

CCRC has considerably changed its way of running since 7.1 (2009 as this [release notes history illustrates](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21233090))

Since those [eclipse definition files should be under source control anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818239/classpath-and-project-check-into-version-control-or-not/2819639#2819639), this shouldn't be an inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

VonC - great comment.  That was the issue - we're creating our projects outside the clearcase view and importing the code into that project.  However, the correct way to make the buttons functional is to create the project within the folder where the view is.  That will enable the  checkin/checkout functionality.

Whether or not that is a bug in CCRC is left up to the reader - the way we used to do it with previous CCRC versions worked fine, but that is not the same way it's working now.