# adding android project to git

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git

Which are the files that I have to ignore when adding a project to git?
Should I add the .classpath file?
What is the purpose of .classpath?
Im using eclipse and pushing to a Jenkins server

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Typical gitignore file for android would include this:

```
# built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# files for the dex VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties
```

From [Gitignore on github](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore)

While creating a project in Eclipse, by default it creates a .classpath file in the project directory. That file will be used for storing file names and other dependent files needed in the classpath to compile and execute the project successfully. Normally this file will be updated automatically when ever you update the project libraries etc.

You should add it to git in my opinion. See this thread for more:

[.classpath and .project - check into version control or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818239/classpath-and-project-check-into-version-control-or-not)