# Is there any guideline of "What to share on Github" regarding RCP developments?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, version-control

I recently started developing a plugin, which consist of several Eclipse Plugin-Projects. I use Maven/Yycho as a build tool and GitHub as version control system.

Now I was wondering what to push to my GitHub repositories. The POM files and Feature/Updatesites as well? It seems that this stuff is:

- very User specific (the path are relative to the file structure on my computer)
- do other developers need that stuff or should I give them the freedom of choosing their own build tools?

To clarify, I have right now 6 Eclipse projects:

```
*.plugin1
*.plugin1.tests
*.plugin2
*.releng
*.feature
*.p2updatesite
```

Would it be good practise to share everything? From my feeling I would say I will only share `plugin1+tests` & item # 2 (without the `pom` files) so that everyone can take care themselves about building.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you actually mean RCP rather than RPC?

Comment: @jon-skeet I am sorry, yes RCP is what i meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to add to your repo:

- anything that can easily be regenerated
- anything with local paths specific to a user

Regarding building, ideally you should version at least a script able to generate the right pom, in order for a new contributor to be able to get going as fast as possible after cloning it.
If you can have config files with only *relative* paths (instead of absolute one), *then* you can include those, for others to use.
See for instance "[`.classpath` and `.project` - check into version control or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2819639/6309)".

Comment: OK, thanks for the link and input, quite a topic as i can see :)