# how to remove a .project file from git without breaking checkouts on different computers

Tags: git

I have two local copies of the a project on two different computers (and a remote origin on github)

I just realized I accidentally committed the .project file, which of course, must be different on each machine.

- on computer A, I have computer As .project file
- on computer B, I have computer Bs .project file.
- in github, I think i have computer As .project file.

Computer A has done an update, committed and pushed.
Now I want to pull the changes to B, but it wont let me because the local .project file is not committed.

What can I do?  If I use tortoise gits "delete (keep local)" feature on computer B, then commit, presumably it will delete .project from the master repo on github, then next time I pull on computer A, I will lose my local .project file and it will break.

any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a file from a Git repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesyste)

Answer (score 1):

First, in computer A, record the deletion of the `.project` and push:

```
git rm --cached .project   # preserve the file on the disk 
                           # while removing it from the index
git add -u .project
git commit -m "Remove .project"
git push
```

Then, in Computer B, you can pull: the `.project` shouldn't be impacted.

---

Note that the `.project` can be versioned because it doesn't have to be different.
See for instance "[`.classpath` and `.project` - check into version control or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2819639/6309)"

Answer (score 0):

Create a .gitignore file, put all the file names which you want to ignore into the .gitignore and then commit it.

Comment: stop tracking those file, commit and then put it into your .gitignore