# Project files under version control?

Tags: version-control, projects-and-solutions

I work on a large project where all the source files are stored in a version control except the project files. This was the lead developer's decision. His reasoning was:

- Its to time consuming to reconcile the differences among developers' working directories.
- It allows developers to work independently until their changes are stable

Instead, a developer initially gets a copy of a fellow developer's project files. Then when new files are added each developer notifies all the rest about the change. This strikes me as far more time consuming in the long run.

In my opinion the supposed benefits of not tracking changes to the project files are outweighed by the danger. In addition to references to its needed source files each project file has configuration settings that would be very time consuming and error prone to reproduce if it became corrupted or there was a hardware failure. Some of them have source code embedded in them that would be nearly impossible to recover.

I tried to convince the lead that both of his reasons can be accomplished by:

- Agreeing on a standard folder structure
- Using relative paths in the project files
- Using the version control system more effectively

But so far he's unwilling to heed my suggestions. I checked the svn log and discovered that each major version's history begins with an Add. I have a feeling he doesn't know how to use the branching feature at all.

Am I worrying about nothing or are my concerns valid?

Comment: What kinf of project files are these ? visual studio .sln files ?

Comment: See also for illustration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337304/which-eclipse-files-belong-under-version-control/337317#337317 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116121/do-you-keep-your-project-files-under-version-control/119377#119377

Answer (score 4):

Your concerns are valid. There's no good reason to exclude project files from the repository. They should **absolutely** be under version control. You'll need to standardize on a directory structure for automated builds as well, so your lead is just postponing the inevitable.

Here are some reasons to check project (*.*proj) files into version control:

- **Avoid unnecessary build breaks.** Relying on individual developers to notify the rest of the team every time the add, remove or rename a source file is not a sustainable practice. There will be mistakes and you will end up with broken builds and your team will waste valuable time trying to determine why the build broke.
- **Maintain an authoritative source configuration.** If there are no project files in the repository, you don't have enough information there to reliably build the solution. Is your team planning to deliver a build from one of your developer's machines? If so, which one? The whole point of having a source control repository is to maintain an authoritative source configuration from which you build and deliver releases.
- **Simplify management of your projects.** Having each team member independently updating their individual copies of your various project files gets more complicated when you introduce project types that not everyone is familiar with. What happens if you need to introduce a WiX project to generate an MSI package or a Database project?

I'd also argue that the two points made in defense of this strategy of not checking in project files are easily refuted. Let's take a look at each:

> > Its to time consuming to reconcile the differences among developers' working directories.

Source configurations should always be setup with relative paths. If you have hard coded paths in your source configuration (project files, resource files, etc.) then you're doing it wrong. Choosing to ignore the problem is not going to make it go away.

> > It allows developers to work independently until their changes are stable

No, using version control lets developers work in isolation until their changes are stable. If you each continue to maintain your own separate copies of the project files, as soon as someone checks in a change that references a class in a new source file, you've broken everyone on the team until they stop what they're doing and carefully update their project files. Compare that experience with just "getting latest" from source control.

Comment: Could you expand upon your answer. The reasons I've given him haven't been convincing enough.

Comment: I've expanded on my original answer. Let me know how it goes with your lead.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a project checked out of SVN should be working, or there should be tools included to make it work (e.g. autogen.sh). If the project file is missing or you need knowledge about which files should be in the project, there is something missing.

Automatically generated files should not be in SVN, as it is pointless to track the changes to these.

Answer (score 0):

Project files with relative path belong under source control.

Files that don't: For example in .Net, I would not put the .suo (user options) web.config (or app.config under source control.  You may have developers using different connection strings, etc.

In the case of web.config, I like to put a web.config.example in.  That way you copy the file to web.config upon initial checkout and tweak what settings you'd like.  If you add something that needs to be added to all web.config, you merge those lines into the .example version and notify the team to merge that into their local version.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the IDE and configuration of the project. Some IDEs have hard-coded absolute paths and that's a real problem with multiple developers working on the same code with different local copies and configurations. Avoid absolute path references to libraries, for example, if you can.

In Eclipse (and Java), it's fine to commit `.project` and `.classpath` files (so long as the classpath doesn't have absolute references). However, you may find that using tools like Maven can help having some independence from the IDE and individual settings (in which case you wouldn't need to commit `.project`, `.settings` and `.classpath` in Eclipse since m2eclipse would re-create them for you automatically). This might not apply as well to other languages/environments.

In addition, if I need to reference something really specific to my machine (either configuration or file location), it tend to have my own local branch in Git which I rebase when necessary, committing only the common parts to the remote repository. Git diff/rebase works well: it tends to be able to work out the diffs even if the local changes affect files that have been modified remotely, except when those changes conflict, in which case you get the opportunity to merge the changes manually.

Answer (score 0):

That's just retarded.  With a set up like that, I can have a perfectly working project containing files that are subtly different from everyone else.  Imagine the havoc this would cause if someone accidentally propagates this mess into QA and everyone is trying to figure out what's going on.  Imagine the catastrophe that would ensue if it ever got released to the production environment...!