# What file(s) does eclipse store Java code style settings to?

Tags: java, eclipse

I spent quite a bit of time modifying my Java code style settings to be the way I like.

For example, go to `Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Clean Up / Formatter / Code Templates`.
I've set eclipse to use white space instead of tab chars, customized the heading on the top of java files, and a whole bunch of other stuff.

Now I'm working on a different computer and had to install a new copy of Eclipse Helios.
Is there a file or set of files I can reuse so I don't have to keep setting this up everytime?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you haven't set "project specific settings", it is in

```
workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs
```

If you have "project specific settings", it is in the "`.settings`" directory of your project.

```
<profile kind\="CleanUpProfile" name\="t1" version\="2">
  <setting id\="cleanup.remove_unused_private_fields" value\="true"/>
  <setting id\="cleanup.always_use_parentheses_in_expressions" value\="false"/>
  ...
```

That latter option (project specific settings) makes it easier for you to version it in your source control tool, as part of the other project files you would want to get back when doing a checkout of a new version of your project somewhere else.

See "[Do you keep your project files under version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116121/do-you-keep-your-project-files-under-version-control/119377#119377)" for more.

Comment: Formatter settings (if specified) are stored in `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` in the same directory.

Answer (score 3):

Every single one of the options under `Windows - > Preferences - > Java - > Code Style` has the option to `export` the current setting to an XML file. You can then `import` that XML file into the other Eclipse install.

And store it in your SCM.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Juno on Mac. I can't find the Export option.

Comment: In Eclipse Neon, you can import/export settings for four different areas separately: Clean up, Code templates, Formatter, Organize imports. There is no import/export for everything at the same time, though.

Answer (score 0):

Dont waste time trying to find the file in eclipse's settings area.  Instead click the "edit" button on your settings profile and export it to a file of your choosing.