# Eclipse Spring Tool Suite workspace broken

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

After forced shut down of an Eclipse STS workspace it doesn't start up, the error in .metadata/.log is:

```
!SESSION 2015-02-06 11:32:47.154 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.6.3.201411281414-RELEASE-e43
java.version=1.7.0_60
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -data /home/myHome/STSWorkspace -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-02-06 11:35:09.243
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.impl.ToolBarSeparatorImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.MToolBar
```

Startup with -clean option didn't work. Any idea on how to fix the .metadata directory?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this error is related to your workspace or the STS installation. What happens if you select a different or fresh and clean workspace? Does that work?

If not, I would re-install a fresh copy of STS, since the error looks a bit like an incompatibility between different parts, maybe an incomplete update or something like that.

If starting STS with a different workspace works just fine, I woudl completely delete the .metadata directory of your workspace while STS is NOT running. Then restart STS (the workspace will be empty, but the projects are still around on dics since you deleted the .metadata directory only). Go to "Import Existing Projects into Workspace", select the workspace location in the upcoming dialog and re-import those existing projects into your workspace.

Comment: other workspaces are still working so it's a workspace issue and not a STS installation problem. I'll delete the .metadata but in this way I'm loosing the formatting configuration that I created for that workspace?

Comment: Yes, but you can try to backup that data. It is stored in a specific file in the workspace (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790241/what-files-does-eclipse-store-java-code-style-settings-to), so you could backup that file and put it back into your new workspace on the file system level (while STS/Eclipse is not running).