# How do I make a Scala project "Import from git"able in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, scala

I have a Scala project setup and working in my workstation. I want to share the whole project (not only the source files, but also the whole eclipse project) on a shared git-repo in such a way that everyone can clone the shared repo and then import the eclipse project from it. The point being there is (ideally) no need to create an Eclipse project once you cloned from the shared repo, but rather import the project that's already there. Insights ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

- create your eclipse project right along your sources (and not in the Eclipse workspace)
  You can do it with **[SbtEclipsify](https://github.com/musk/SbtEclipsify)**.
- version in Git your [Eclipse project files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116121/do-you-keep-your-project-files-under-version-control/119377#119377).

If you don't have any absolute path in your project classpath, you will be fine.