# How to build an autobuild system and regression test system for subversion?

Tags: svn, virtual-machine, build-automation, regression-testing

I have been asked to do the following:

a) Build a VM for a subversion server
b) Figure out an autobuild system and regression test system
c) Write documentation or simple instructions to get people started with subversion

I am not really sure what these instructions mean - although I have a vague idea. If you know could you provide some dot points and appropriate terms that I should google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following links might help:

- VM means Virtual Machine. See [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) for example.
- [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org) is a popular version control system.
- An automated build system is something like [Cruise Control](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net).
- Excellent documentation for Subversion can be found in the [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) online book.

Figuring out how to integrate tools like the above into your workplace environment will be up to you.

Comment: For some reason SO didn't let me select your answer as the correct one back then - and still won't.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find some useful links in this question: [how-to-setup-a-sophisticated-java-development-infrastructure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545520/how-to-setup-a-sophisticated-java-development-infrastructure)